# I overloaded a virtual function, but it didn't work

Tags: c++

So far I have done the following work:

```cpp
class Stamp{
 public:
    virtual std::string GetStampName() const { return "undefined"; }
};
```

```cpp
class FooStamp : public Stamp {
 public:
    std::string GetStampName() const override { return "foo-stamp"; }
};
```

I use it like this:

```cpp
FooStamp fooStamp;
std::cout << "foo-stamp:" << fooStamp.GetStampName() << std::endl;

const Stamp stamp = fooStamp;
std::cout << "stamp:" << stamp.GetStampName() << std::endl;
```

The actual output is as follows：

```
foo-stamp:foo-stamp
stamp:undefined     // expected: foo-stamp
```

Types converted to base classes are not working. What did i do wrong.

Is there a way to make the override effective also ensure that the object is copied by value.

Comment: Virtual methods only work with pointers and references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re experiencing [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) since a `FooStamp` object doesn’t fit into a `Stamp` object, and copying it therefore slices off the subclass parts.

Runtime polymorphism requires the use of references or pointers:

```
Stamp const& stamp = fooStamp;
std::cout << "stamp:" << stamp.GetStampName() << "\n";

Stamp const* pstamp = & fooStamp;
std::cout << "stamp:" << pstamp->GetStampName() << "\n";
```

Both work. But beware of lifetime: once `fooStamp` goes out of scope, so do pointers and references to it.

Comment: I didn’t use the pointer because I was worried about the life time when using it externally. Is there a way to avoid? Is copying by value possible to achieve the above requirements. thanks

Comment: @MengHanYu Copying polymorphic objects is actually surprisingly hard and there isn’t really a shortcut. That’s why traditional OOP is best avoided in C++ as much as possible (there often better ways anyway). You will need a virtual `clone` function for that. But this method needs to allocate dynamic storage, so you will need to handle lifetime explicitly. In most cases you therefore want to create a `Clone` function that returns a `std::unique_ptr<Stamp>`.

Comment: @MengHanYu • Object lifetime management in C++ is not a simple subject, because C++ has a lot of options for object life time management.  There's no one size fits all, because there are many different scenarios.  In the code snippet in your question, `Stamp const&` is the one I'd use.  For the general situation, `std::unique_ptr` is an excellent _owning_ smart pointer.